Finding invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AMB = M'$ and what it means with respect to the bases of each
I am working on a linear algebra problem:

We are given A linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with a matrix $M$:
$$ 
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 4 & 6 & 8 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And I need to find to invertible matrices $A$ and $B$, such that $AMB = M'$, where $M'$ is the matrix:
$$ 
M'=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Progress so far:
I have found a basis for the kernel and the image of $T$, as follows:
$$
\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}} 
\def\Span{\operatorname{Span}} 
\def\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}} 
\def\id{\operatorname{id}} 
\def\std{\operatorname{std}} 
\Im(T) = \Span\{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\
\end{pmatrix} \}
$$
and
$$\Ker(T) = \Span\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
-2\\1\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix}
-3\\0\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
-4\\0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix} \right\} $$
What I am thinking of:
I am trying to get an intuitive understanding by relating the new matrix to the basis of the kernel and image. So I am trying to get the intuition behind it and possibly minimize computation.
Otherwise, I am wondering if I can use:
$M' = \bigl({}_\alpha[\id_{\mathbb{R}^2}]_{\std}\bigr)
\bigl({}_{\std}[M]_{\std}\bigr)
\bigl({}_{\std}[\id_{\mathbb{R}^4}]_\beta\bigr)$ where $\bigl({}_\alpha[\id_{\mathbb{R}^2}]_{\std}\bigr)$ is $A$ and  $\bigl({}_{\std}[\id_{\mathbb{R}^4}]_\beta\bigr)$ is $B$, but I am a bit confused on what my choice of bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ should be.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence

The columns $B_2,B_3,B_4$ should be a basis of $\ker T$, and $A$ should map $\operatorname{im}T$ onto $Span{\begin{pmatrix}
1\0\
\end{pmatrix} }$.

Why does our choice $B_1$ not matter? additionally, how do we understand that this is the purpose of each of B and A?


Whatever $B_1$ such that $B$ is invertible, if $B_2,B_3,B_4$ spans $\ker T$ then $T(B_1)$ will span $\operatorname{im}T$ (look at any proof of the rank-nullity theorem). 2) By scrutinizing $M'$.


One possible approach: express $M$ and $M'$ as $xy^T$ and $uv^T$ respectively for some nonzero vectors $x,u\in\mathbb R^2$ and $y,v\in\mathbb R^4$. Then find two invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $Ax=u$ and $y^TB=v^T$. Now $AMB=(Ax)(y^TB)=uv^T=M'$.

You can use the elementary matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, which guarantees invertibility for $A$. Note that the last three columns of $B$ belong to $Ker(AM)$. Therefore, you can construct the last three columns of $B$ using the basis of $Ker(AM)$.
This results in $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&-3&-4\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$.
